# Vuejs build checkbox dynamically from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I´m trying to build and checkbox from the setCheckbox method. The idea is to set dynamically the names to build the checkbox array.

```
<div id='example-3'>
   <div v-for="(item, index) in names" :key="index">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="item.name" v-model="item.checked">
      <label :for="item.name">{{ item.name }}</label>
   </div>
   <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
</div>
```

I removed the names array  that supported the checkbox, in order to pass dynamically the new values.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#example-3',
    data() {
        return {
            names: []
            /*  Below is how the names should receive the array to support the checkbox
        [
      {
        name: '',
        checked: false
      }, {
        name: '',
        checked: false
      }, {
        name: '',
        checked: false
      }
      ]
     */
        }
    },
    method: {
        setCheckbox: function() {

            var txt = "These arethe names for checkbox {Rob} is 20, {Carlos} is 22 and {Mike} is 19."

            var regExp = /{([^}]*)}/g;

            var matches = value.match(regExp);
            var arrCheckbox = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                var str = matches[i];
                arrCheckbox.push(str);

                // set the names in the array
                const names = arrCheckbox
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        checkedNames() {
            return this.names.filter(item => item.checked).map(name => name.name)
        }
    },
})
```

Basically trying to pass array to names dynamically, method sets values require to build names.
https://jsfiddle.net/bernlt/aj6apozq/114/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several things you need to correct.

1. You called the methods attribute `method`.
2. You don't call the `setCheckbox()` while initializing the component. You need to do this in either `created()` or `mounted()`. If you want to dynamically watch the example string, you would also have to watch this string and the reset the `names` array.
3. You don't save the names effectively. You just create a constant with the name `names` but you must assign it to the vue component (`this`).
4. You pushed a string into the array (the name), but you actually wanted to push an object containing a string and a boolean.
5. You could improve your code, if you split the logic of the loop and extracting the string from the checkbox view. You can do this by creating a component for the checkbox which is looped over multiple times. Then, you'd have a single state in a checkbox component with a name and a boolean.

The first four things should be fixed now in this snippet (I did not run it):

---

```
<div id='example-3'>
   <div v-for="(item, index) in names" :key="index">
      <input type="checkbox" :id="item.name" v-model="item.checked">
      <label :for="item.name">{{ item.name }}</label>
   </div>
   <span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
</div>
```

I removed the names array  that supported the checkbox, in order to pass dynamically the new values.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#example-3',
    data() {
        return {
            names: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setCheckbox() {
            this.names = [];

            // you might want to extract this string and recall this function after it changes
            var txt = "These arethe names for checkbox {Rob} is 20, {Carlos} is 22 and {Mike} is 19."

            var regExp = /{([^}]*)}/g;
            var matches = value.match(regExp);

            for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                this.names.push({
                   name: matches[i],
                   checked: false
                });
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        checkedNames() {
            return this.names.filter(item => item.checked).map(name => name.name)
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.setCheckbox();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues.

- you're not calling setCheckbox()
- several errors.

Here's something closer to what you're looking for:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#example-3',
    data() {
        return {
            names: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setCheckbox: function() {

            var txt = "These arethe names for checkbox {Rob} is 20, {Carlos} is 22 and {Mike} is 19."

            var regExp = /{([^}]*)}/g;

            var matches = txt.match(regExp);
            var arrCheckbox = [];

            console.log(matches);
            for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
                var str = matches[i].replace(/{(.*)}/, '$1');
                this.names.push({name: str, checked: false});
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        checkedNames() {
            return this.names.filter(item => item.checked).map(name => name.name)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setCheckbox();
    }
})
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmbldwn/3Lrbw56s/8/